# How to access this variable in Object.defineProperty value flag?

Tags: javascript, properties, pseudo-class

I'm attempting to find a way to initialize a property value that is appended to all instances of a JavaScript pseudoclass with localized value references without the need to manually iterate over every instance, as an example the following code:

```
function A() {
    this.a = '0';
}

var a = new A();
var b = new A();

document.write(a.a + a.b + a.c + '<BR />');

A.prototype.b = '1';
Object.defineProperty(A.prototype, 'c', {
    writable: true,
    value: (function() { return(this.a + '|'); })()
});

document.write(a.a + a.b + a.c + '<BR />');

b.c = '3';

document.write(a.a + a.b + a.c + '<BR />');
document.write(b.a + b.b + b.c + '<BR />');
```

Outputs:

```
0undefinedundefined
01undefined|
01undefined|
013
```

But under the desired condition would output:

```
0undefinedundefined
010|
010|
013
```

Edit:

For clarification, the value should be initialized to the properties of the object accessed via "this." when the property is appended to the object, not in a delayed manner on a get or set call and without using additional local properties.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Can you elaborate on what you want? So you want to have `c` based on the value of `a` but `a` is only defined at instantiation? and you want `c` to be able to be overridden by assignment?

Comment: I'm trying to find a way to assign a property to a pseudoclass after multiple instances of that pseudoclass have been created, drawing the value from one or more members of each instances effected without manually iterating over every preexisting instantiation.  In the example this would be calling a.a and b.a separately to determine the relative value of A.c (that is, a.c and b.c separately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want a getter function that dynamically computes the value from the `a` property:

```
Object.defineProperty(A.prototype, 'c', {
    get: function() {
        return(this.a + '|');
    },
    set: function(x) { // overwritable:
        // create normal property directly on the object (not on the prototype)
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'c', {
            value: x,
            writable: true
        });
    }
});
```

Your current code works like

```
A.prototype.c = (function() { return(this.a + '|'); })(); // IEFE
```

where `this` is the global object and `a` of course undefined.

Comment: I only want to set the initial value for the property using local parameters, beyond that it should behave like a normal property and without using any extra localized variables like _c.  I would like to use the value and writable flags, which are incompatible with the get and set flags.

Comment: "using local parameters" is incompatible to a static "value" descriptor. Test it, it will behave exactly as requested.

Comment: Ah, it does work - it looked a lot like the other one so I didn't look closely at the set definition - very nice :)

Comment: One other question, is it possible to get this to set the value immediately?  Doing it in a delayed manner (waiting until it is changed) doesn't work well when you need to initialize the property to the state the object is in when it is initially appended to the properties.

Comment: What do you mean by "immediately"? What do you mean by "it is initially appended to the properties"?

Comment: The call to defineProperty is at a stage after instances of the pseudoclass have been created, the value should be initialized at that moment for each individual instance without manually iterating over them and not delayed by whatever interval of time is between that appendage and calls to get/set as whatever members of the individual instances the value property is initialized from may change between the point at which the new property is added and those get or set calls.

Comment: That is impossible. To "initialize" the value from instance properties, you need that instance. But you don't have any without looping over all of them or waiting until the value gets requested for a specific instance. And I don't see any reason why you would need it before requesting it.

Comment: Think of if you had to modify .a after setting .c, .c only takes part of it's initial value from .a, it isn't dependent upon it beyond that.  Though if it's impossible in JS I'll go ahead and mark your answer as correct - it is otherwise the best one and I can loop over the instances when required while initializing them, it just feels like something where there would be a built-in method of doing this with a faster loop than that achievable through JS loops due to the type-specific nature of the code.

Comment: A more direct way of stating this might be: function A() { this.a = 1; this.b = this.a + 1; } Object.defineProperty(A.prototype, 'c', {
    get: function() {
        return(this.b + 1);
    },
    set: function(x) { // overwritable:
        // create normal property directly on the object (not on the prototype)
        Object.defineProperty(this, 'c', {
            value: x,
            writable: true
        });
    }
});

Comment: That is to say, you can't chain together variables when initialized together, because you can't trust that the variables they draw from won't change before they are accessed themselves.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to access `this` then you cannot use the `value` and `writable` descriptor options. You will need to use `get` and `set`. In this case, since you want values you assign to take precedence over the default value, then it is up to you do do that logic.

```
Object.defineProperty(A.prototype, 'c', {
    get: function(){
      // If an overridden values was provided, then return that instead.
      if ('_c' in this) return this._c;
      return (this.a + '|');
    },
    set: function(val){
      this._c = val;
    }
});
```

Comment: I understand this, it was an example to demonstrate the intent.

Comment: @CoryG I misunderstood, I think this should be more inline with what you want.

Comment: It is closer, but I'm trying to do it with a value flag and no secondary property like _c (value can't be set in conjunction with get or set).